# Fetch from database not working?

Tags: php

So I have the code below (and at the top the database connector and session start). However, he doesn't echo the amount of cubes (a valuta on my site).

```
$cubes = mysql_query("SELECT cubes FROM leden WHERE id='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'");

echo "You currently have " . $cubes;
```

What is going wrong here? The database is there, the tables and everything exist.

Comment: *"What is going wrong here?"* - Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code and it will tell you.

Comment: Executing a query returns a resultset, which can't be displayed simply by doing an echo; you then need to fetch each record returned in that resultset, and display the values returned..... as even the worst tutorials and examples will tell you

Comment: But if you're just learning how to use PHP and databases, I'd strongly recommend switching to the MySQLi or PDO extensions (rather than using the old, deprecated MySQL extension that has been dropped from the latest versions of PHP), and learning to use prepared statements with bind variables

Comment: @MarkBaker What do you mean? Is MySQL going to be deleted ? all this work for nothing ??

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: MySQL is not  being deleted from PHP, there are just newer, safer methods for interacting with databases.

Comment: The MySQL extension has already been dropped from the latest version of PHP; in favour of the MySQLi or PDO extensions

Comment: I was going to *vote to close* but there doesn't appear to be an RTFM option for the reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysql_query function returns you a result set. So if you want to get the information you must also do :

```
$cubesRow = mysql_fetch_object($cubes);
echo "You currently have " . $cubesRow->cubes;
```